# Difference between (.|[\r\n]){1,1500} and ^.{1,1500}$

Tags: asp.net, regex

What is the difference between below two regular expressions

```
(.|[\r\n]){1,1500}

^.{1,1500}$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first matches up-to-1500 chars, and the second (assuming you haven't set certain regex options) matches *a <strike>first</strike> single line* of up-to-1500 chars, *with no newlines*.

Comment: ...and it (the second one) does so only if either the string contains no newlines at all, or the option `RegexOptions.Multiline` is set because otherwise the `$` means "end of string" instead of "end of line".

Answer (score 1):

`.` does not match new lines.

Comment: It does if you specify `RegexOptions.SingleLine`.

Answer (score 1):

First expression matches **some** <= 1500 **characters** of the file(or other source).
Second expression matches **a** entire **line** with charsNumber <= 1500.

`.` matches any character *except \n newline*.

Comment: `.` can match all chars if you specify `RegexOptions.SingleLine`.  But even then, there's a subtle difference; the first matches up-to-1500 chars, and the second matches *the first* up-to-1500 chars.

Comment: I am using this against multi line textbox of ASP.NET.
While viewing this in safari i am getting error "Invalid regular expression: regular expression too large"

Comment: with both or only one of them?

Comment: first one is giving me error in safari 3.0. What i need to do is that, i need to restrict the user to enter more than 1500 characters and need to display an error message. i am using regular expression validator for this.

Comment: do you need 1500 chars per line, or in general?

Comment: in my text box i should be able to enter not more than 1500 characters. not in a line.

Comment: So you can use `(.|[\n]){1,1500}` (or use `regexOptions.Multiline`). Did you tried in other that Safari browsers?

Answer (score 1):

The second one matches the first 1500 characteres of a line IF the line contains 1500 characters or less

Comment: say not the *first*, but *all* of them.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for use in a RegularExpressionValidator, you probably want to use this regex:

```
^[\s\S]{1,1500}$
```

This is because the regex may be run on either the server (.NET) or the client (JavaScript).  In .NET regexes you can use the `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag (or its inline equivalent, `(?s)`) to make the dot match newlines, but JavaScript has no such mechanism.

`[\s\S]` matches any whitespace character or anything that's *not* a whitespace character--in other words, anything.  It's the most popular idiom for matching *anything including a newline* in JavaScript; it's much, *much* more efficient than alternation-based approaches like `(.|\n)`.

Note that you'll still need to use a RequiredFieldValidator if you don't want the user to leave the textbox empty.